# JavaFX TableView using FX Objects

Tags: java, uitableview, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I am trying to put a stack panel in my `TableView` and I keep getting errors.

I suspect it is my lack of understanding of creating the Cell Value Factory.

My Code looks like:

```
TableColumn obj = new TableColumn("Func " + i);
        final int index = i;
        obj.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String>, TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String>>() {



            @Override
            public TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String> call(final CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> cdf) {
                if (index + 2 >= cdf.getValue().size()) {
                    return null;
                }
                //return new SimpleStringProperty(cdf.getValue().get(index + 2));
                return new TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String>(){
                    Label funcLbl = new Label(cdf.getValue().get(index+2));
                    StackPane sp = new StackPane();


                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                        sp.getChildren().add(funcLbl);
                        setGraphic(sp);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        obj.setMinWidth(100);
        this.getColumns().add(obj);
```

And the Error I am getting is

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'StringProperty [bean: PinTable[id=null, styleClass=table-view], name: skinClassName, value: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin]' for control PinTable[id=null, styleClass=table-view]
java.lang.ClassCastException: mapr.components.mainui.render.table.MyTable$3$1 cannot be cast to javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:1209)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:1179)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:543)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:105)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell$1.invalidated(TableCell.java:93)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:112)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.resizeToFit(TableColumnHeader.java:619)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader$1.invalidated(TableColumnHeader.java:138)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScene(Node.java:661)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.computeDirtyScene(Parent.java:599)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.sceneChanged(Parent.java:612)
    at javafx.scene.Node$4.invalidated(Node.java:699)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScene(Node.java:661)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.computeDirtyScene(Parent.java:599)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.sceneChanged(Parent.java:612)
    at javafx.scene.Node$4.invalidated(Node.java:699)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScene(Node.java:661)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.computeDirtyScene(Parent.java:599)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.sceneChanged(Parent.java:612)
    at javafx.scene.Node$4.invalidated(Node.java:699)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScene(Node.java:661)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Parent.java:425)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableObservableList.callObservers(VetoableObservableList.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.setAll(ObservableListWrapper.java:303)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableObservableList.setAll(VetoableObservableList.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.setAll(ObservableListWrapper.java:314)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.updateChildren(Control.java:947)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$100(Control.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$1.invalidated(Control.java:207)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$1.set(Control.java:186)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$1.set(Control.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:1047)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$500(Control.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.invalidated(Control.java:972)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.set(Control.java:964)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:902)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7415)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7383)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7377)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7377)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3800(Scene.java:170)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2202)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:329)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I am trying to convert from using a

```
public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> cdf)
```

and only returning a `SimpleStringProperty` to returning a `TableCell<ObservableList<String>`, String> that has a `StackPane` as its content with the `String` held in a `Label` (I want to create actions based on clicking on the stack pane).

Any help on understanding the transition would be great!

Comment: I did something similar in an answer [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196659/javafx-architecture-in-building-dynamic-rows/20198220#20198220)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CellValueFactory** is to populate data in  cells of column from model object ..

Example :

```
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName"));
```

If you want to render data in all cells of table column then you must use **cellFactory**.